# Как отключить автокомплит комбобокса?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        fromComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
```

Стоит такой мод, но всё равно срабатывает автокомплит.
В целом, мне нужно нужно оставить дропдаун лист, без дополнения в самой строке.

Update 10:29 17.08.2016
"Больше кода"

Метод висит в событии изменения текста комбобокса

```
 private void searchComboBoxParametr(ComboBox control)
        {
            if (control.Focused)
            {
                string[] list = null;

                if (control.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    if (control.Text.Length < 2)
                        return;

                    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

                    string before = control.Text;

                    if (control.Text.Length != 0)
                        while (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Milliseconds < 300)
                            Application.DoEvents();

                    if (!control.Text.Equals(before))
                        return;

                    int curCarretPosition = control.SelectionStart;

                    if (control.Name.Equals("locComboBox"))
                    {
                        list = namesList.Where(person =>
                        person.ToString().ToLower().Contains(control.Text.ToLower())
                        ).Select(person => person.местонахождение).Distinct().ToArray();
                    }
                    else if (control.Name.Equals("fromComboBox")
                        || control.Name.Equals("toComboBox1"))
                    {
                        list = namesList.Where(person =>
                        person.ToString().ToLower().Contains(control.Text.ToLower())
                        ).Select(person => string.Format("{1} {0} {2}", person.имя, person.фамилия, person.отчество)).ToArray();
                    }
                    else if (control.Name.Equals("titleComboBox"))
                    {
                        list = titlesList.Where(title =>
                        title.ToString().ToLower().Contains(control.Text.ToLower())
                        ).Select(title => title).ToArray();
                    }

                    control.Items.Clear();
                    control.Items.AddRange(list);
                    if (control.Items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        control.MaxDropDownItems = control.Items.Count < 15 ? control.Items.Count : 15;
                        control.DroppedDown = true;
                    }
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

                    control.SelectionStart = curCarretPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (control.Name.Equals("locComboBox")
                        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromComboBox.Text))
                    {
                        list = namesList.Where(person =>
                        person.ToString().ToLower().Contains(control.Text.ToLower())
                        ).Select(person => string.Format("{1} {0} {2}", person.имя, person.фамилия, person.отчество)).ToArray();

                        fromComboBox.Items.Clear();
                        fromComboBox.Items.AddRange(list);
                    }
                    else if (control.Name.Equals("fromComboBox")
                        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(locComboBox.Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Test");
                        list = namesList.Where(p =>
                        p.ToString().ToLower().Contains(control.Text.ToLower())
                        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.местонахождение)
                        ).Select(p => p.местонахождение).ToArray();

                        locComboBox.Items.Clear();
                        locComboBox.Items.AddRange(list);
                    }

                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Контрол свой программно создаёте?

Comment: Добавлен Visual Studio. Там же по стандарту выставлены параметры на "None"

Comment: Тогда почему в комментарии к ответу написано `Перед этим кодом только создание комбобокса`

Comment: в конструкторе формы есть 
            InitializeComponent(); после него fromComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;. Касательно комбобокса больше ничего нет

Comment: Есть мысль, что в методе searchComboBoxParametr() мод меняется на SuggestAppend после заполнения его Item'ов.

Comment: Дебагом не проверяли теорию эту?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44093/discussion-between-anatol-and-denisjnewb).

Comment: Проверил. Показывает None после добавления Item'ов

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `control.DroppedDown = true;` эту строку. Не понятно, зачем она вообще там.

Comment: Нужна для отображения динамического списка из этих самых Item'ов.

Comment: Это нечто вроде хинта. Зачем это нужно? Может быть путаете этот хинт с автокоплитом?

Comment: Прошу прощения за ввод вас в заблуждение. До меня только что дошло, что я написал кривую реализацию того же автокомплита (Только не понятно, почему droppeddown так себя ведет). Переписал полученный результат поиска в автокомплит с модом Suggest, вместо того, чтобы совать его в Item'ы и все вышло как задумывалось. Спасибо, вы избавили меня как минимум от 1 дня мозголомки

Comment: Вспомнил зачем я вообще писал свою реализацию автокомплита. Мне нужен автокомплит, который ищет совпадения в любой части строки, а не только с самого начала. Например: Кочемасов Евгений Бдыжин, стандартный будет искать только если начать с "Кочем...", мне нужен поиск и по имени и по отчеству. Думаю это уже вопрос из другой темы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему Вы решили, что при таком "моде" автокомплит не должен срабатывать?

> `Suggest` Выводит вспомогательный раскрывающийся список,
>   сопоставленный элементу управления, в котором выполняется правка.Этот
>   список содержит одну или несколько предложенных строк завершения.

```
fromComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
```

> `None` Отключает возможность автоматического завершения в элементах
>   управления `ComboBox` и `TextBox`.

Comment: Даже если выставить "None", работает мод SuggestAppend

Comment: Тогда дайте больше кода

Comment: Обновил тело темы. Перед этим кодом только создание комбобокса и присвоение мода "None"